# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
def StartGame():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Maths Quiz - Trigonometry and Pythagoras' Theorem | Start The Game")
    root.geometry("640x480")
    root.configure(background = "gray92")
    TotScore = 0
    Count = 0
    while Count < 10:
        AnswerReply = None
        WorkingArea = Text(root, width = 70, height = 10, wrap = WORD).place(x = 38, y = 100)
        n = GetRandomNumber
        Question,RealAnswer = QuestionLibrary(Opposite,Adjacent,Hypotenuse,Angle,n)
        AskQuestion = Label(root, text = Question).place(x = 38, y = 300)
        PauseButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Pause").place(x = 380, y = 10)
        HelpButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Help", command = helpbutton_click).place(x = 460, y = 10)
        QuitButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.destroy).place(x = 540, y = 10)
        AnswerEntry = Entry(root)
        AnswerEntry.place(x = 252, y = 375)
        SubmitButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = submit_answer).place(x = 276, y = 400)
        Count += 1
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the function used with the submit button:

```
def submit_answer():
    Answer = AnswerEntry.get()
    print(Answer)
    TotScore,AnswerReply = IsAnswerCorrect(Answer,RealAnswer)
    ScoreLabel = ttk.Label(root, text = TotScore).place(x = 10, y = 10)
    AnswerReplyLabel = ttk.Label(root, text = AnswerReply).place(x = 295, y = 440)
```

And this is the error I get when I click on the SubmitButton

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ANNIE\Documents\School\Computing\Project\Python\GUI Maths Quiz.py", line 178, in submit_answer
    Answer = AnswerEntry.get()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm trying to make a quiz game where I get an input from the user using the AnswerEntry Entry box, however it is telling me that the object has no attribute get, please help!

Comment: Is `AnswerEntry` a global? You don't declare it as such in `StartGame()`.

Comment: I've defined it outside of the function, but I haven't put "global AnswerEntry" anywhere...

Comment: Okay I set AnswerEntry as a global variable and it worked, thank you Martijn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the `AnswerEntry = Entry(root)` line to affect a global name defined outside of the function, you need to declare it a global inside of your `StartGame()` function:

```
global AnswerEntry
AnswerEntry = Entry(root)
```

Assignment to a variable in a function makes that variable name local to the function only. It appears you assigned an integer value to the global `AnswerEntry` elsewhere, so `submit_answer()` sees that when you call `AnswerEntry.get()`.

You should really avoid globals though.

Comment: +1. And you should _definitely_ avoid reusing globals to mean an integer sometimes, an `Entry` other times…

Answer (score 0):

`AnswerEntry` is an intenger and not an object, so you can't call that method on him.

Maybe you're missing object instance?